# How to save thrift struct in a user friendly JSON format with enums by numbers in Golang?

Tags: go, enums, code-generation, marshalling, thrift

Task.thrift *(Thrift version 0.9.3)*

```
enum AttributeApp {
  a = 1,
  b = 2,
  c = 3
}

typedef i32 attrTypeId

struct Task {
  1: required attrTypeId type_id,
  2: required list<AttributeApp> app_to,
}
```

Generated Apache Thrift code for Java marshal enums by numbers.

> $ thrift -r --gen java Task.thrift

```
TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer(new TSimpleJSONProtocol.Factory());
String json = serializer.toString(task);
Util.writeLog("task.json", json);
```

How to generate Apache Thrift code for Golang with JSON marshal enum by number instead of name?

> $ thrift -r --gen go Task.thrift

This example make enums by strings:

```
bt, err := json.Marshal(task)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = ioutil.WriteFile("task.json", bt, 0666)
```

This example make enums by numbers, but add two extra numbers in any list of json:

```
transport := thrift.NewTMemoryBufferLen(1024)
protocol := thrift.NewTSimpleJSONProtocolFactory().GetProtocol(transport)
ts := &thrift.TSerializer{transport, protocol}
bt, err := ts.Write(task)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = ioutil.WriteFile("task.json", bt, 0666)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TJSONProtocol` instead, this provides you with an interchangeable, JSON-based data format.

The [`TSimpleJSONProtocol` is not intended to be used as a serialization format, at least not when you plan to read it back into your program using Thrift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753659/how-to-convert-thrift-objects-to-readable-string-and-convert-it-back).

Other than that, if `TSimpleJSONProtocol` produces different output for Java and Go, you may have found an inconsistency and consider filing a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT) ticket including a suitable test case.

Comment: Interested in serialization in a user friendly JSON format. TJSONProtocol works fine, but isn't user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove [this](https://github.com/apache/thrift/commit/549a9e1e6dfbfaf1f7685dc5e26440c501517738#diff-1b57800912b80e54a5fb23aee7873271R926) commit and re-make thrift-0.9.3 then use json.Marshal/Unmarshal.